Getting intersection of subset of multiindex dataframe from Pandas
I have some a multi index df, with a month and then facilityIDs and a TotalSpend value for each facility. I'm trying to aggregate the TotalSpend across all facilities for a quarter, where they have data in all 3 months of the quarter AND all 3 months of the quarter in the previous year.

In my example data, I tried getting a subset of April, May, and June from the df and then doing an inner join, but when I try that I get an error that it's not a df, but a df that using df.loc[[date]] is giving me.  I would basically like to check which facilityIDs show up in all 3 months of the quarter and only keep those values.
Desired output:
The desired output would be the sum of the spend in Q2 2024 across all facilities that have data in all 3 months of Q2 2024, and then the sum of the spend in Q2 2023 across all of those same facilities.
In this case it would be Facility 1 only, so Q2 2024 sum of 450 and Q1 2024 sum of 300.

Code:
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def open_file(path, quarter_number, months):
    df_raw = pd.DataFrame({'Date':["2024-04-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01", "2024-06-01","2024-05-01","2023-04-01","2023-05-01","2023-06-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01","2023-05-01","2023-06-01", "2023-04-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01"],
                         'FacilityID': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4],
                         'TotalSpend': [100,110,120,50,70,90,100,110,150,140,120,60,90,190,150]
    }).set_index('Date')
    df = df_raw.groupby(['Date', 'FacilityID'])['TotalSpend'].sum()
    # print(df)

    cur_dates = []
    prev_dates = []

    for month in months:
        cur_date = datetime.date(2024, month, 1)
        prev_date = datetime.date(cur_date.year - 1, month, 1)
        cur_dates.append(cur_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))
        prev_dates.append(prev_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))

    #this is where i'm having issues
    cur_data =df.loc[[cur_dates[1]]].join(df.loc[[cur_dates[1]]], on='FacilityID' ,join = "inner")
    prev_data = df.loc[prev_dates[0]:prev_dates[-1]]

    # print(cur_data)
    # print(prev_data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    change = open_file("path",2 ,[4,5,6])
    print(change)


Can you provide the exact expected output for clarity?

Just added some more context. I would like to get the aggregate sum across all facilities for the current quarter and the previous quarter that satisfy the condition of having 3 months of data in the current quarter and 3 months of data in the previous quarter.

Please [edit] the question and add the full expected output, this is more explicit than a description.

I added in the picture of the desired output

I hope I've understood your question right:
# `df_raw` is the same as in your question:

df_raw.index = pd.to_datetime(df_raw.index)
df_raw["month"] = df_raw.index.month

df_raw = df_raw.groupby(
    [
        pd.PeriodIndex(df_raw.index, freq="Q"),
        "FacilityID",
    ]
).agg({"TotalSpend": "sum", "month": "nunique"})

df_raw = df_raw[df_raw.month == 3]

print(df_raw["TotalSpend"].reset_index())

Prints:
     Date  FacilityID  TotalSpend
0  2023Q2           1         300
1  2024Q2           1         450

